# Magento 2 - Override template files in module

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

What is the correct way to override a template file ? I need to display custom text in place of In Stock and Price on the product page.

[image]

I want to override the template -

> Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml for In stock.

However, I cannot figure what would be the correct XML for it.

I've tried -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.type">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/type/default.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I can't find out which file should be overridden to change the text for price.

I would really appreciate it if you could explain how to write the XML file for overriding templates.

UPDATED catalog_product_view.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.type">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/type/default.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Vendor/Module/view/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml -

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView */?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>

<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <div class="stock available" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock with static text') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to override below file using module:

> Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

Create

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

and put

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.type">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="{Vendor}_{Module}::product/view/type/default.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Now create `default.phtml` at:

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

Now you can add you code in `phtml`.

Hope above will Help!

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you please explain how to create the xml file. How do you find which container and block to use? Do the attributes name and as have to be same as in Magento_catalog's catalog_product_view.xml?

Comment: Which files should I edit to change the Price?

Comment: First I check file name using template path hint. after find file name we can search that file in xml. we get reference block/container name from here.

Comment: you can see for override I have used same reference container, block class, name etc. I have only change phtml with our module!

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Above code is tested and working at my end

Comment: I tried changing "In stock" to "in stock with us" but no use. It still reads from Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml. I am using Magento community edition 2.3.1

Comment: @coderGeek, there can be many reason, first check your module is working, if you are not on developer mode you need to `deploy content`, try to remove `var`, `generated` folder etc....

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Could you please let me know what you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried the code that you've posted in a fresh installation of magneto. I executed `rm -rf generated/code/*`,`bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Have you created module ?

Comment: Yes...all of this is in a custom module

Comment: Could you please add your module code in OP ?

Answer (score 0):

create layout file in your custom module as below path:

> {vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.type">
           <referenceBlock name="product.info.simple">
               <action method="setTemplate">
                  <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/view/type/default.phtml</argument>
               </action>
            </referenceBlock>
       </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

For example: Here we override product/view/type/default.phtml in custom module.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. I tried to override the template `\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\renderer\actions\edit.phtml` in my module.